# Who assigns private IP addresses?

Tags: ip, ip-address, private-ip

Suppose I have a router and a local network, can I freely assign my devices private IP addresses (as many as I want, up till there are no more private IP addresses left)? Who decides how many private IP addresses I can have?

Comment: I would be happy to sell you some PABs if you need more ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are PRIVATE. If you wire a house, who decides how many doors you can have?

The IP address spaces that are NOT USED ON THE INTERNET are defined in an RFC. Private addresses are part of that (actually THE part of it) and are in there.

You can use whatever you want from that. There is no authority. They are not existing on the internet.

Obviously if you VPN etc. to another entity, they can do the same, so you better coordinate.

Comment: @ryn take a note of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network feel free to assign so many ips as you like, but remind to choose the correct subnet.